# How to keep AutoSuggestBox suggestion box open in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Using the new AutoSuggestBox control in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT XAML), I am trying to keep the suggestion box open all the time -- even after the user clicks a suggestion.

I have no problem starting with the suggestion box open by programmatically setting `AutoSuggestBox.IsSuggestionListOpen = true;`

Then I hook the SuggestionChosen event like this:

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args) {
    sender.Text = args.SelectedItem.ToString();
    sender.IsSuggestionListOpen = true;
}
```

But unfortunately the suggestion box still closes after selecting an item, even though I set IsSuggestionListOpen to true.

Any help with getting it to stay open after a selection would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to this is to hook the `LayoutUpdated` event.

I have the AutoSuggestBox in a PickerFlyout, so I only want the suggestion box open if the PickerFlyout is open (obviously).  So I set a `Tag` property on the button that opens the PickerFlyout to identify if the PickerFlyout is open or closed.  Then in the `LayoutUpdated` event of the AutoSuggestBox I set the `IsSuggestionListOpen` property to `true` if the PickerFlyout is open (and `false` if it's not).

The code:

```
private void PickerFlyout_Opened(object sender, object e) {
    ActivatePickerFlyoutButton.Tag = "open";
}

private void PickerFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e) {
    ActivatePickerFlyoutButton.Tag = "closed";
}

private void AutoSuggestBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e) {
    AutoSuggestBox.IsSuggestionListOpen = ((ActivatePickerFlyoutButton.Tag as string).Equals("open"));
}
```

That is the only place I need to set the `IsSuggestionListOpen` property, since the `LayoutUpdated` event fires at all the right times.